# submit form to different plugin

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have a users plugin and a leads plugin.  I have a leads form under my "sign in" form incase people aren't already signed up.

The problem is when I:

```
$this->Form->create('Leads.Lead', array('plugin'=>'leads','controller'=>'leads','action' => 'add')
```

The url of the form submission is /users/leads/add instead of just /leads/add

I thought using the dot syntax on the "create" statement would do the trick, but it's still trying to submit to a leads controller within the Users plugin.  How do I set this up so that any leads form I create *anywhere* will always point back to my leads plugin?  I'd like to refrain from using extra routes if possible.

Comment: Define a string URL instead: `/path/to/your/file` - this way you know **exactly** where Cake is going to point your action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your routing file .

```
Router::connect(
    '/leads/:action',
    array('controller'=>'leads','plugin'=>'leads')
);
```